# 2 identical csv files but with carriage returns and line feed issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, csv, parsing

I have 2 identical test files. Doing a diff on them returns:

<(od -c file1.csv) <(od -c file2.csv)
**file1:** a   b   c  \r  \n   a   b   c  \r  \n   a   b   c

**file2:** a   b   c  \r  \n   a   b   c  \r  \n   a   b   c  \r  \n

So apparently, Excel appends \r \n in creation of the .csv file

My csv parse function:

```
var reader = new FileReader();        
       reader.onload = function(e) {
       var contents = e.target.result;    
       var rows = contents.split(/[\r\n]{1,}/g);
    }
```

How do I fix my regex in my parse function above?My hasDups() function only works with file 2

```
function toLowerCase(s) {
    if (typeof(s) === 'string') {
        return s.toLowerCase();
    }

    return s;
}

function hasDups(arr) {
    return (arr.length !== _.uniq(arr, false, toLowerCase).length);
}

$scope.add= function() {

            var subs = [];


                    angular.forEach($scope.csvModel, function(sub) {

                        var subCopy = angular.copy(sub);

                        // Concatenates each field into one separated by spaces
                        subs.push(Object.keys(subCopy).map(function(key) {
                            return subCopy[key];
                        }).join(' '));
                    });



            }

            if ($scope.hasDups(subs)) {
console.log("dups exsist")
}
}
```

sample file test.csv:

abc
abc
abc

abc

abc

The output( rows) should remove all unncessesary linebreaks, spaces, etc, and just show abc one per line.

Comment: Can't you just trim any trailing `\r` and/or `\n` characters from the end of the file before further processing, and/or `.filter()` out any `rows` elements that contain nothing but whitespace?

Comment: i did , if(rows[rows.length-1]==''{
rows.pop()
}  
which removed '' from the end

Comment: Are the files really as shown with space characters in between and around the `\r` and `\n` characters, because if so you'll be getting more than one unwanted element at the end of the array for file 2. Also, how do you call `hasDups()`? You don't show a directly link between your file reading code and `hasDups()`.

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to omit the `\r \n` completely, dont use the square bracket because it is for range and character class e.g. `[a-d] or [a-zA-Z0-9]`

You can try to change the regex to `var rows = contents.split(/ *\r \n */g);`

It should give the same array for both test file 1 and 2

Hope it helps!

Comment: this regex dispalys the file words in one line. I need mine to be displayed one per line

Comment: So let me clarify, `\r \n` is the line break for each line right? So it only appears at the end of the line, instead of each cells. Am I correct? if yes, then my regex is doing what you need

Comment: Check my updated post. When i compare the 2 files, I only see \r and \n at the end of the file, which causes an error. But also, I need your regex to be updated so that It is displayed one per line below each other. Right now, it is being displayed like this: abc abc abc. The regex I have right now works in terms of displaying them, not sure if it works fine in removing the \r and \n

Comment: and for some reason, my hasDups function only works with file 2, the one with the \r and \n

Comment: I dont really get what you mean. But I'm taking a wild guess here. Try using this regex instead `var rows = contents.replace(/( *\r \n *)/g, "\n");`.
If you can, show us your hasDups method as well. There are plenty of reason why it works for file2 and not for file1

Comment: Updated post. And I tried this, it's displaying every letter sepertly, line by line. so it's doing a b c a b c a b c , each letter right below another. I need abc abc abc right below each other